# Bubble sorting function seems not working

Tags: javascript, bubble-sort

Lately, I'm so confused on what's wrong with my code.

**Problem:** I want to bubble sort everytime I input an integer in my input field.

Outcome should be : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 > but everytime I input 2 digits ex. the 1 and 10 the result will be

bug result: 1,10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

```
var array = [];
function newfunction(){
  var newArray = . document.getElementById("number").value
  array.push(newArray);
  console.log(array);
  for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for (var j = array.length; j>1; j++){
      if(parseInt(array[i-1]) < parseInt(array[i])){
        var temp = array[i-1];
        array [i-1] = array [i]; 
        array[i]=temp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are doing something totally wrong... It's comparing as strings...

Comment: How are you calling `newfunction` share your HTML

Comment: @PraveenKumar what should I change?

Comment: One problem that I can see is you are not using `j` inside loop's body. So essentially, you are just comparing 2 elements multiple times

Comment: @hazy Try this: `var newArray = parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);` and get rid of `j` loop...

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal yes i have inside of my <button> tag onclick="myfunction()"

Comment: also j would run to infinity so Iexpect this function to compare the first two elements forever...

Comment: @Boris You are right... My browser screwed up... LoL.

Comment: `j>1; j++` Missed it totally... :-p

Comment: I will try to change my code

Comment: @hazy can you turn it into a snippet so we can see it run?

Comment: `for (var j = array.length; j>1; j++)` ??

Comment: First, that isn't the code you're running; it would fall into an infinite loop.  Please post the correct code, and also for the case that's generating bad output you need to specify the input.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [];
function newfunction(){
  array.push(document.getElementById("number").value);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < (array.length - i - 1); j++) {
      if(parseInt(array[j]) > parseInt(array[j+1])) {
        var tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[j+1];
        array[j+1] = tmp;
      }
    }        
  }
  console.log(array);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" onblur="newfunction()"/>
```

Have a look at this code. it sorts the array with bubble sort.

you must type a number in input and press tab or click outside to add number to array and see sorted result.